# how does an android phone app check the phone country setting

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, country-codes

I bought a new Samsung phone in the USA for my wife (S20+) and used the Samsung "copy" app to transfer the settings from her old phone (which we bought while we were living in Taiwan.) Now, there is a collection of Playstore Apps that cannot be installed because they say they are not "not available in your country." Neither I nor Samsung support can figure out where/what setting is causing this problem.

I had the same problem with my new Samsung S10+ which was fixed by clearing the cache in the PlayStore app. But that didn't help with my wife's phone.

Comment: Try creating a new google account and while creating new account select current country and use that id in Google Play app. I hope it will work.

Comment: Seemed like a good idea so I created a new gmail account. There was nothing that allowed me to set any country (current or not.) I searched through the account settings and still could not find any country setting.

I even restarted the phone but the app install still fails in the same way. "Not available in your country"

There MUST be something an app checks to generate this message. What does/can an app check that would be location or country?